# How to fix incorrect chi2pdf results in MATLAB R2019A

Tags: matlab, chi-squared, probability-distribution

I am working with MATLAB R2019A (Slightly out of date, I know) on Linux Mint 19.1. For the task I am trying to perform, I need the chi2pdf function, but when I tried to use it, it gave incorrect results. Just to test it, I tried the following, and this is what I got:

```
>> chi2pdf(0.95, 29)
ans =
```

5.8154e-16

```
>> chi2pdf(0.95, 29.0)
ans =
```

5.8154e-16

```
>> chi2pdf(single(0.95), single(29))
ans =
```

5.8154e-16

```
>> chi2pdf(double(0.95), double(29))
ans =
```

5.8154e-16

The reason that I tried different variations was because I saw other questions regarding similar problems in MATLAB, so I thought it might be related to some single-to-double conversion issue. I am installing R2019B to see if that helps, but in the mean time, any suggestions that anyone has would be much appreciated.

Comment: Why do you think that result is incorrect? What value did you expect to obtain?

Comment: Sorry about that. It seems I made a careless mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silly mistake. This was a case of the alpha value mixed up the the x value. For anyone whose time was wasted looking at this, I am sorry.